# How do I install drjava in linux from terminal?

Tags: linux, software-installation, java, programming

I've downloaded `drjava-stable-20100816-r5366.jar` file which is the drjava version for Linux. How do I install it on my machine?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

I have OpenJDK Java 6 runtime and Sun Java 6 runtime on my machine already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ? Looks like you only got one jar file, so just launch it is fine:

`java -jar drjava-stable-20100816-r5366.jar`

**EDIT**

You could put a shortcut on your desktop, put these things to ~/Desktop/XX.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=What ever
GenericName=What ever
Exec=java -jar /absolute/path/to/drjava.jar
Icon=gedit
Type=Application
```

Just double click on the desktop icon to launch it.  You might need to change the icon of the launcher, by right click and there should be some options, not sure.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to launch dr java without typing java -jar drjava-stable-20100816-r5366.jar?

Comment: @pyler answer updated